# Add two text fields together that include commas and decimals with JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

In order to add a feature to a existing application I'm attempting to use JavaScript to add together input fields which need to stay as text field types and show the end result text field as a total of those fields. I can easily make it work adding the numbers together. However the numbers will be typed in with commas and decimals every time. When this happens the adding breaks and doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas of how I could possibly make this work?

HTML CODE

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="the_input_id">
<input type="text" id="the_input_id1">
<input type="text" id="total">
```

JavaScript

```
  $(function() {

    $('#the_input_id').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });

    $('#the_input_id1').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });

    var updateTotal = function () {
      var input1 = parseInt($('#the_input_id').val());
      var input2 = parseInt($('#the_input_id1').val());
      if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {
          if(!input2){
              $('#total').val($('#the_input_id').val());
          }

          if(!input1){
                $('#total').val($('#the_input_id1').val());
          }

      } else {          
            $('#total').val(input1 + input2);
      }
    };

    var output_total = $('#total');

    var total = input1 + input2;

   output_total.val(total);

 });
```

Comment: Since that function is assigned to a `var` it will not be accessible unless it's assigned before your Events. If it was a regular function it wouldn't matter. You need to put your `output_total` stuff in your updateTotal function. Of course, with your implementation I don't see a need for those Anonymous functions in keyup, you can just replace that with `.keyup(updateTotal);`.

Comment: can you provide some examples of input and out put expectations ?

Comment: I think it would be easier to strip the commas before converting the values to a Number then format the output total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read my comment above, then take a look here:

```js
//<![CDATA[
 /* js/external.js */
$(function(){
var num1 = $('#num1'), num2 = $('#num2'), total = $('#total'); // why get them again unless they're dynamic ?
function updateTotal(){
  var s = num1.val().replace(/,/g, ''), s2 = num2.val().replace(/,/g, '');
  if(s === '' && s2 === ''){
    total.text('Awaiting Input').addClass('er');
  }
  else if(isNaN(s) && isNaN(s2)){
    total.text('Numbers Required').addClass('er');
  }
  else if(s === ''){
    total.text('Awaiting First Number').addClass('er');
  }
  else if(isNaN(s)){
    total.text('First Input Requires Number').addClass('er');
  }
  else if(s2 === ''){
    total.text('Awaiting Second Number').addClass('er')
  }
  else if(isNaN(s2)){
    total.text('Second Input Requires Number').addClass('er');
  }
  else{
    total.text(((+s)+(+s2)).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2})).removeClass('er');
  }
};
num1.keyup(updateTotal); num2.keyup(updateTotal);
}); // end jQuery load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
input[type=text]{
  width:100px; padding:0 3px;
}
.er{
  color:#900;
}
#total{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <input type='text' id='num1' /> &plus;
    <input type='text' id='num2' /> &equals;
    <div class='er' id='total'>Awaiting Input</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you can use `+` in front of a String to cast it to a number... and that JavaScript has a Floating Point Number Math issue.

**Here is a `<form>` example:**

```js
//<![CDATA[
 /* js/external.js */
$(function(){
var form = $('#form'), num1 = $('#num1'), num2 = $('#num2'), total = $('#total'); // why get them again unless they're dynamic ?
function updateTotal(){
  var s = num1.val().replace(/,/g, ''), s2 = num2.val().replace(/,/g, '');
  if(s === '' && s2 === ''){
    total.val('Awaiting Input').addClass('er');
  }
  else if(isNaN(s) && isNaN(s2)){
    total.val('Numbers Required').addClass('er');
  }
  else if(s === ''){
    total.val('Awaiting First Number').addClass('er');
  }
  else if(isNaN(s)){
    total.val('First Input Requires Number').addClass('er');
  }
  else if(s2 === ''){
    total.val('Awaiting Second Number').addClass('er')
  }
  else if(isNaN(s2)){
    total.val('Second Input Requires Number').addClass('er');
  }
  else{
    total.val(((+s)+(+s2)).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2})).removeClass('er');
  }
};
form.submit(function(e){
  console.log(form.serialize());
  // run a bunch of tests using if conditions and the like before AJAXing - $.post example shown
/*
  $.post('sendToPage.php', form.serialize(), function(jsonResult){
    // should get echo json_encode($objOrAssocArray); from PHP as jsonResult now
  }, 'json');
*/
   // prevents old school submission
  e.preventDefault();
});
num1.keyup(updateTotal); num2.keyup(updateTotal);
}); // end jQuery load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
input[type=text]{
  width:100px; padding:3px 5px;
}
.symbol{
  display:inline-block; width:18px; text-align:center;
}
.er{
  color:#900;
}
#total{
  width:calc(100% - 236px);
}
input[type=submit]{
  width:100%; height:30px; background:#007; color:#fff; border:0; border-radius:5px; margin-top:4px; cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <form id='form'>
      <input type='text' id='num1' name='num1' /><div class='symbol'>&plus;</div><input type='text' id='num2' name='num2' /><div class='symbol'>&equals;</div><input type='text' class='er' id='total' name='total' value='Awaiting Input' readonly='readonly' />
      <input type='submit' id='sub' value='Submit Test' />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code will fail with his example of 1,000,000 + 1,000,000.25

Comment: I think it works and shows decimals now. But don't count on Floating Point Math to work.

Comment: this works but the total is not inside of a text box which is the issue. I tried change it back to a input for the total but the calculation no longer works.

Comment: Shouldn't matter that it's not in an input. If you change it to an input, then it's `.val()` instead of `.text()`.  The calculation would still work. You want that for a `<form>`? I would avoid old school form submission. Use AJAX. Perhaps you want to `.serialize()` a form later. I'll throw in another example. It won't `.serialize()` since that's not part of the question, though.

Comment: I added the `.serialize()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```js
var num1 = "1,000,000.00"
var num2 = "1,000,000.25"

var re = /,/gi;
var num1a = num1.replace(re,''); // strip commas
var num2a = num2.replace(re, ''); // strip commas
var sum = Number(num1a) + Number(num2a); // convert to Number and add together

console.log(sum); // before formatting

var total = Number(sum).toLocaleString(); // formatted
console.log(total)
```

Comment: the decimals stay but the commas are gone and I have to account for larger numbers so commas every 3 places after first two decimals. for instance 1,000,000.00 + 1,000,000.25  would need to total and display as 2,000,000.25 in final text field

Comment: I have updated the code above and used your specific example to prove it is now working

Comment: Don't forget that `Number(...)` can return `NaN`. You will want to check if `total` is `NaN` before attempting to output it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this by simply extracting only numbers from any string the user inputs:

```js
$(function () {
  var $firstInput = $('#first');
  var $secondInput = $('#second');
  var $totalInput = $('#total')

  $firstInput.keyup(updateTotal);
  $secondInput.keyup(updateTotal);

  function extractNumbers(str, def) {
    var onlyNumbers = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
      var currChar = str.charAt(i);
      
      if (!isNaN(currChar)) {
        onlyNumbers += currChar;
      }
    }

    return parseInt(onlyNumbers) || def;
  }
  
  function updateTotal () {
    var valInput1 = extractNumbers($firstInput.val(), 0)
    var valInput2 = extractNumbers($secondInput.val(), 0)
    var total = valInput1 + valInput2;
    $totalInput.val(total);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="first number..." id="first">
  <input type="text" placeholder="second number..." id="second">
  <input type="text" placeholder="total number..." id="total">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: look what happens when it gets to the decimal places and strips them, it makes 1,000.00 into 100000!

Comment: yes that is right :) I thought he does not care about any strings, so in that case he can use your solution but this thing is always tricky...

Comment: This does add them together correctly however it doesn't show commas and decimals on the grand total. the grand total just displays as a number without the commas and decimal.. unsure how to add them back in after stripping out.

Comment: You are right sir, I misunderstood the question :-| sorry